# Read a text file and uppercase first letter of every word in C

Tags: c, text, file-handling

I wanna read an existing file and uppercase the first letter of every word. So I thought I can figure out words from the space in between them but I don't know how to focus on first letter so I just make all uppercase, here's my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
int chr,i;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("DATA.txt" , "r");

do
{
    chr = fgetc(fp);
    chr = toupper(chr);
    printf("%c" , chr);

    if (chr==' ')
        {
            getch();
        }

} while(chr!=EOF);

fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: why do you have this line `getch();`?

Comment: just to see program flow slowly, nothing else

Comment: A debugger would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... how to focus on first letter ...(?)

Detect the first letter of each word by saving the previous character.  Let a word being with 1) any sequence of `<white-space><Letter>` or 2) if the first character read is a letter.

Other trouble: `EOF` detection too late.  Check for `EOF` right after `fgetc()`

```
// EOF test too late
  chr = fgetc(fp);
  chr = toupper(chr);
  printf("%c" , chr);
} while(chr!=EOF); // too late

// Instead
  chr = fgetc(fp);
  if (chr == EOF) break;
```

All together

```
int previous = ' ';
while ((chr = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
  if (isspace(previous) && isalpha(chr)) {
    chr = toupper(chr);  // uppercase first letter of every word
  }
  printf("%c" , chr);
  previous = chr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
bool upperNext = true;

while((chr = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if(chr == ' ' || chr == '\r' || chr == '\n') {
       upperNext = true;
    } else if(upperNext) {
       chr = toupper(chr);
       upperNext = false;
    }

    printf("%c" , chr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want to do that of waiting after every space is read (assumed reason for your getch() there), then you may try setting i = 0 before your do loop. Then if( i == 0 ) then chr = toupper(chr) and increment i. Finally, within the if( chr == ' ') include i = 0 again.

Also, if you want to consider other spacing characters (linebreaks, tabs, etc) then you should `include <ctype.h>` and use isspace() function like `if( isspace(chr) )` instead of `if( chr == ' ' )`.